# Copying 16bit grascale image to 48 bit rgb image

Tags: image, grayscale, 16-bit

I have raw data of 16 bit grayscale image. I wanted to make 48 bit RGB image by copying same value into all 3 channels.
Presently I'm doing:

```
BYTE *bit=new BYTE[512*512*6];
int j=-1;
int i=0;
for(int k=0;k<512*512;k++)
{
    bit[i]=ptr[++j];
    bit[++i]=ptr[j];
    bit[++i]=ptr[j];
    bit[++i]=ptr[++j];
    bit[++i]=ptr[j];
    bit[++i]=ptr[j];
    i++;
}
```

This code results in a yellowish tinge. Is something like shifting bits required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
BYTE *bit=new BYTE[512*512*6];
int j=-2;
int i=-1;
for(int k=0;k<512*512;k++)
{
    bit[++i]=ptr[++++j];
    bit[++i]=ptr[j+1];
    bit[++i]=ptr[j];
    bit[++i]=ptr[j+1];
    bit[++i]=ptr[j];
    bit[++i]=ptr[j+1];
}
```

This will do the following.

1st round:

```
    bit[0]=ptr[0];
    bit[1]=ptr[1];
    bit[2]=ptr[0];
    bit[3]=ptr[1];
    bit[4]=ptr[0];
    bit[5]=ptr[1];
```

2nd round:

```
    bit[6]=ptr[2];
    bit[7]=ptr[3];
    bit[8]=ptr[2];
    bit[9]=ptr[3];
    bit[10]=ptr[2];
    bit[11]=ptr[3];
```

...etc.

Actually you don't need `i` and `j`:

```
BYTE *bit=new BYTE[512*512*6];
for(int k=0;k<512*512;k++)
{
    bit[6*k]=ptr[2*k];
    bit[6*k+1]=ptr[2*k+1];
    bit[6*k+2]=ptr[2*k];
    bit[6*k+3]=ptr[2*k+1];
    bit[6*k+4]=ptr[2*k];
    bit[6*k+5]=ptr[2*k+1];
}
```

---

The reverse operation (48-bit to 16-bit):

```
BYTE *bit=new BYTE[512*512*6];
for(int k=0;k<512*512;k++)
{
    ptr[2*k]=bit[6*k];
    ptr[2*k+1]=bit[6*k+1];
}
```

If the RGB image is *not* grayscale, then you have to [calculate the luminance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale#Colorimetric_.28luminance-preserving.29_conversion_to_grayscale) of every pixel and copy the luminance into the 16-bit grayscale image:

```
BYTE *bit=new BYTE[512*512*6];
for(int k=0;k<512*512;k++)
{
    unsigned int R=(bit[6*k]<<8)+bit[6*k+1];
    unsigned int G=(bit[6*k+2]<<8)+bit[6*k+3];
    unsigned int B=(bit[6*k+4]<<8)+bit[6*k+5];
    unsigned int Y=(unsigned int)round(0.2126*R+0.7152*G+0.0722*B); 
    ptr[2*k]=Y>>8;
    ptr[2*k+1]=Y&0xFF;
}
```

This code assumes that the most significant byte is stored first (big-endian). If you use little-endian storage:

```
BYTE *bit=new BYTE[512*512*6];
for(int k=0;k<512*512;k++)
{
    unsigned int R=(bit[6*k+1]<<8)+bit[6*k];
    unsigned int G=(bit[6*k+3]<<8)+bit[6*k+2];
    unsigned int B=(bit[6*k+5]<<8)+bit[6*k+4];
    unsigned int Y=(unsigned int)round(0.2126*R+0.7152*G+0.0722*B); 
    ptr[2*k+1]=Y>>8;
    ptr[2*k]=Y&0xFF;
}
```

Comment: And what about reverse operation i.e. 48 bit to 16bit image

Comment: I added the reverse operation to the end of my answer.